# Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'FooModelDTO'

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I'm using an `Observable` to return an object from service, that service checks if its item exist in cache otherwise it calls an http request and return the http's `Observable`, in case the item exist in cache i'm using rxjs `from`.

`foo.service.ts`:

```
private foos: FooModelDTO[] = [];
getFoo(id: string) : Observable<FooModelDTO> {
    var foo = this.foos.find(x => x.id === id);
    if (foo) {
        return from(foo);    --> error!        
    }            

    return this._foosAPIService.getFooById(id);
}
```

`foo-api.service.ts`:

```
getFooById(id: string) : Observable<FooModelDTO> {
    return this._httpClient.get<FooModelDTO>(
        this._configService.resourceApiURI + 'foos/' + id
    );
}
```

`foo.model.ts`:

```
export class FooModelDTO {
  public id: string;

  constructor (
    id: string
  ) 
  {
    this.id = id;
    // other properties...
  }
}
```

> error TS2322: Type 'Observable<{}>' is not assignable to type
> 'Observable'.
> Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'FooModelDTO': id, imagePath, updateDate, title, and 6 more.

How to overcome this error? and return the cache result immediately in case it exist.

Comment: You need to use `of ` operator instead of using `from`.

Comment: are you sure you want to get `foo` from `foos` array based on the index, not on the `id` property inside the 'FooModelDTO' ?

Comment: Hey @DurgeshPal thanks, I've updated the question to use `find`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

The problem is u access your array with a `string` instead of a `number`. For that reason the type of `foo` is `unknown` instead of `FooModelDTO`.

**Original answer**

To answer your question we have to know what `this.foods` type is. If the typing is correct it should work. If you cannot fix its type, you can later cast `foo`.

```
var foo: FooModelDTO = this.foos[id] as FooModelDTO;
if (foo) {
    return from(foo);
}
```

Also `from` needs an input of type `ObservableInput<any>`. I would recommend to use `defer`. Since the `Observable`  returned if you have a cache miss is lazy, its a good idea to make the `Observable`, you get on cache hit, also lazy.

```
return defer(() => of(foo));
```

Comment: Hey @kai, see updated question, the `this.foos` is of the same type

Comment: I've updated the question again to use `find` instead of index access

Comment: @ShaharShokrani Doesnt this change fix the problem? I would expect that change to fix the problem with your typings?

Comment: Actually the `of` fixed the issue

Comment: @ShaharShokrani The of was a different issue. I copy pasted your code into stackblitz and after resolving the first issue, the secound issue was the of. The error message you posted, does not match the `of` problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is in the Observable you are using. 
**from** is used to turn an array, promise, or iterable into an observable.

You should use `of` instead of `from`.

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';

private foos: FooModelDTO[] = [];
getFoo(id: string) : Observable<FooModelDTO> {
    const foo = this.foos.find(x => x.id === id);
    if (foo) {
        return of(foo);       
    }            

    return this._foosAPIService.getFooById(id);
}
```